# Constructor optimization in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-optimization

I've read that those two syntaxes aren't the same when instantiating an object:

```
ClassName c1(p);
```

and

```
ClassName c1 = ClassName(p);
```

(or without parameters due to constructor)

I've read the second syntax creates two objects one to be temporary with given parameters then copy constructor gets called. But when I create an object the second way, the `cout` in the constructor and destructor prints one time each. That leads me to think if I am misinformed and these two ways are completely the same or the compiler automatically optimizes it and that causes it?

If it's because optimization is there a way to disable the optimization to see the difference between them?

Comment: The two lines are exactly equivalent since C++17 (there is no temporary) and even before that the temporary copy was allowed to be elided (as you observe). I am sure there is a good duplicate somewhere.

Comment: The two syntaxes aren't the same.  One is direct-initialization, the other is copy-initialization.  They may (and usually do) result in the same code at runtime, however.